# How to make read buffer from standard input when run with --remote-tab-silent option?

Tags: vim, pipeline

The following command successfully launches vim that reads the edit buffer from standard input.

```
echo hi | vim -
```

But this one does not work.

```
echo hi | vim --remote-tab-silent -
```

When the above command is run, the following warning occurs and vim quits.

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

Why does it not read from standard input in the second case?

The help message of vim seems to indicate that it should have worked?

```
$ vim -h | head
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 31 2015 23:36:07)

usage: vim [arguments] [file ..]       edit specified file(s)
   or: vim [arguments] -               read text from stdin
   or: vim [arguments] -t tag          edit file where tag is defined
   or: vim [arguments] -q [errorfile]  edit file with first error

Arguments:
   --           Only file names after this
   -g           Run using GUI (like "gvim")
$ vim -h | grep remote
   --remote <files> Edit <files> in a Vim server if possible
   --remote-silent <files>  Same, don't complain if there is no server
   --remote-wait <files>  As --remote but wait for files to have been edited
   --remote-wait-silent <files>  Same, don't complain if there is no server
   --remote-tab[-wait][-silent] <files>  As --remote but use tab page per file
   --remote-send <keys> Send <keys> to a Vim server and exit
   --remote-expr <expr> Evaluate <expr> in a Vim server and print result
```

Comment: Please tell (if possible, and needed) what exactly you're piping to edit, because there might be another solution.

Comment: I am trying to edit any output from an existing shell command in an existing Vim instance, i.e. I don't want to launch a new instance of Vim. I want to pipe the output of a shell command into an existing instance of Vim such that the output appears in a new tab.

Comment: I  see. Well, if you already has an instance running, maybe you can just open a new buffer or tab (`:enew` or `:tabnew`) and then use a command like `:r!shell_command -args` to read it directly to the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot edit from *stdin* when using `--remote`.

```
:h --remote
```

```
 --remote [+{cmd}] {file} ...
                          Open the file list in a remote Vim.  When
                          there is no Vim server, execute locally.
                          There is one optional init command: +{cmd}.
                          This must be an Ex command that can be
                          followed by "|".
                          The rest of the command line is taken as the
                          file list.  Thus any non-file arguments must
                          come before this.
                          You cannot edit stdin this way |--|.
                          The remote Vim is raised.  If you don't want
                          this use >
                           vim --remote-send "<C-\><C-N>:n filename<CR>"
```

--remote-silent [+{cmd}] {file} ...
                          As above, but don't complain if there is no
                          server and the file is edited locally.

--remote-tab-silent      Like --remote-silent but open each file in a
                          new tabpage.